# How to plot a network flow with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to produce exactly the same picture shown next.

[image]

I started by doing this

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,shapes.geometric}
\pgfdeclarelayer{signal}
\pgfsetlayers{signal,main}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\tikzstyle{printersafe}=[snake=snake,segment amplitude=0 pt]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\sloppy
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[>=triangle 45]
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c1) at (0,0) {};
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c2) at (1,0) {};
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c3) at (0,1) {};
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c4) at (1,1) {};
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c5) at (-0.5,0.5) {$s$};
      \node[circle,draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.3, inner
      sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] (c6) at (1.5,0.5) {$t$};

      \draw [->] (c1) -- (c2);
      \draw [->] (c5) -- (c1);
      \draw [->] (c5) -- (c3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Model}
  \label{fig:sys}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

but this gives me something weird.

[image]

This figure clearly does not produce the desired result. Can you help me?

Comment: Why is it weird? Most of the nodes have no text in them (the `$v_n$` nodes). And the `inner sep` defines the "padding" between the node content and its border.

Comment: Because I would like to produce the same thing but I did not succeed. (It is weird compared to what I would like to have not to what I wrote.)

Comment: The text $s$ and $t$ are not as they are given in the original figure. They are big. How to make them small?

Comment: Also, the arrows are not the same. How can I get the same shapes?

Comment: Yes, I see that they are different, I just thought "weird" was a weird choice of word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is fairly close. Some notes:
 - I removed everything unnecessary from the preamble, and also the `figure` environment and the `resizebox`. ( personally I think `resizebox` should be the last thing you do for scaling a `tikz` diagram, even if it is very simple).

- The reason the node text is "large" compared to the node itself in your code is that you have `inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt`. The `inner sep` defines the distance from the node content to the border, and the node content is always larger than 2pt. I kept the `inner sep` value, but increased the `minimum size` to `20pt`.
- Nodes are positioned relative to each other. For example, the `v_2` node is placed `above right=of c1`, where `c1` is the name of the `s` node. Benefits of this is that

  1. you don't have to worry about absolute coordinates;
  2. it becomes very easy to modify the distance between nodes: just change the values for the `node distance`. In `node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm` the first length is the vertical distance, the second is the horizontal.
- the `arrows.meta` library is a replacement for the `arrows` library, and gives you a lot of potential for customizing arrow heads if needed (see the manual)
- The `fill opacity` applied to the text as well. You could remove the `fill opacity`, and set `fill=gray!30` instead of just `gray`. I instead added `text opacity=1`, which overrides the opacity value from the `fill`.
- I defined a `mycircle` style to avoid repetition.
- Lastly I used a `\foreach` loop to draw the arrows. You could also have multiple `\draw [myarrow] (<node 1>) node[above] {<number>} (<node 2>);`, but with the loop you get less repetition.
- To draw the two parallel arrows I used the angle anchor syntax. E.g. `nodename.60` is the point at the border of the node that is at an angle of 60 degrees from the horizontal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      mycircle/.style={
         circle,
         draw=black,
         fill=gray,
         fill opacity = 0.3,
         text opacity=1,
         inner sep=0pt,
         minimum size=20pt,
         font=\small},
      myarrow/.style={-Stealth},
      node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm
      ]
      \node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
      \node[mycircle,right=of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
      \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
      \node[mycircle,right=of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
      \node[mycircle,below right=of c5] (c6) {$t$};

    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
      c1/c2/8/below,
      c1/c4/11/above,
      c2/c3/11/below,
      c3/c6/4/below,
      c4/c5/12/above,
      c5/c6/15/above,
      c5/c2/4/below,
      c3/c5/7/below,
      c2.70/c4.290/1/below}
       \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);


     % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
     \draw [myarrow] (c4.250) -- node[sloped,font=\small,above,rotate=180] {10} (c2.110);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Grear answer. I use your code, then the shape appears in the left side of the screen. How can we push it more toward center?

Comment: @Redshoes Put the `tikzpicture` in `\begin{center} .. \end{center}`? Might depend on documentclass, but it's no different from an image, or table, or text, that you'd want to center.