# How to find the angle of a path between to nodes relative to one node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to find the angle of a path between two nodes relative to one node. Here is an example of a graph I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341949/how-to-plot-a-network-flow-with-tikz):
[image]

For example let us look at the path P between v_1 and v_2. Relative to v_1 P has the angle 270° (going down to v_2). Relative to v_2 the angle of P is 90° (going up to v_1). For another example let Q be the path between v_2 and v_3. Then, relative to v_2 the angle of Q is 45° (going diagonally up right to v_3). How can I find this angle for arbitrary paths?
The motivation is to do double directed edges such as the two between v_1 and v_2 but for arbitary setups.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the `ext.misc` library.

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {ext.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid(3,4);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,4);
\draw (A)--(B);
\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{anglebetween("A","B")}
\node at (1,0){\ang};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it could not find the library: "Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'ext.misc'. I looked for files named tikzlibraryext.misc.code.tex and pgflibraryext.misc.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees.." Do you know why that could be?

Comment: You need to install the `tikz-ext` package https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext

Comment: I understand. However, after looking at the documentation it just refers to \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints function from pgfmath. So, it would be cleaner to use that package instead I guess. But, thanks anyways.